# Two independent time axes in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My task is to compare some current period's logs with older one. For example - this week logs and previous week logs. But when I create second axis like this

```
scales : {
    xAxes: [
        {
            id: 'A',
            type: 'time',
            position: 'bottom'
        }, {
            id: 'B',
            type: 'time',
            position: 'top'
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an empty section, because all of my xAxes are 'time'-type, and time of points is not same (it is absolutely normal behavior).
[I have this situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xDx0.jpg)

But I need to make independent axes, for example: 
top axis starts at 30sep, ends at 3oct
bottom axis starts at 7oxt, ends at 10oct
and all of them are same length

I've tried to create axes like this

```
let MyScale = Chart.Scale.extend({type: 'time', ticks: this.makePrevDsTicks()});
Chart.scaleService.registerScaleType('myScale', MyScale, {type: 'time'});
```

But without 'ticks' property I have an Error : "TypeError: me.ticks is undefined"
With 'ticks' I can't make it work like 'time' axis - labels are show like 'raw' (like Date objects)

There is behavior I mean, but I need chart with two time x-axes
[Example](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/2.6.0/charts/line/multi-axis.html)
There is a pen [codepen example](https://codepen.io/shake_shake1/pen/Baaojqq)

Comment: Post your full code in codepen.  It will be easier to look into the problem

Comment: of course, added it just now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution was in [time option](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#configuration-options)
All I needed to do was to set `time.min` to last timestamp of 'previous' dataset and `time.max` to first timestamp of 'current' dataset

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/shake_shake1/pen/Baaojqq?editors=1010)